# JavaScript Date getHours returning weird result

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a UTC timestamp stored on a cloud storage as "Sun Feb 22 02:30:00 UTC 2015".

In my javascript, I parsed the UTC time as string to create a Date object.

```
var obsDTStr = 'Sun Feb 22 10:30:00 CST 2015'; // this is correct as I am in Time Zone +8
console.log(obsDTStr);  // console prints out "Sun Feb 22 10:30:00 CST 2015" which is also correct
var obsDT = new Date(obsDTStr);  // create a Date object with the string
console.log(obsDT.toString());  // console prints out "Mon Feb 23 2015 00:30:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)" which is incorrect
```

I am unsure why the result was so weirdly incorrect.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: CST will be interpreted as a US time zone.  So if you are UTC + 8, the Date object will add 14 hours.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
 console.log(obsDT.toUTCString());
```